# Linked List SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a linked list data structure in C# which represents a kind of chain. Now I want to map this chain to a SQLite database. I have the following schema:

```
-- Table: MetaData
CREATE TABLE MetaData (
    Id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    FrameId     TEXT    NOT NULL,
    Unit        INTEGER REFERENCES Units (Id) 
                        NOT NULL,
    Predecessor INTEGER REFERENCES Units (Id),
    Name        TEXT,
    Value       TEXT
);


-- Table: Units
CREATE TABLE Units (
    Id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    UnitName TEXT    UNIQUE
);
```

So every row in the MetaData table offers a "Predecessor" value in addition to the "Unit" value (both pointing to the corresponding entry in the "Units" table). I thought with this approach it should be possible to walk through the "linked list" (MetaData table rows) up to the first entry in a chain. Now I look for a way to get an ordered result based on the "Predecessor" and "Unit" values. Is this possible with "WITH" clause and recursion in SQL?

I tried something like this but this doesn't work and I am little bit lost:

```
WITH RECURSIVE list AS (
SELECT Id, 1 AS Position, Unit, Predecessor
FROM MetaData WHERE Predecessor IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT m.Id, list.Position + 1, m.Unit, m.Predecessor
FROM MetaData m INNER JOIN list mpl ON m.Id = mpl.Id AND m.Predecessor = mpl.Unit
)
SELECT * FROM list
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results, better in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 to clarify what you want.

Comment: In general, things like linked-lists and relational databases don't get along well.  Consider a design that serializes your list into an ordered collection that can be projected into a table (and, uh, unprojected, back into a linked list)

Comment: @forpas: You can find a sample fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8085f/4